# Scraping selective links from a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have created a scraper using python which is parsing links from a webpage. It scrapes 10 links from that site. Is it possible if i want to parse the first 8 links or the last 8 links out of that 10 links? Actually, I can't get any idea how to do so. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "http://www.supplyhouse.com/"
def Selectivelinks(address):
    response = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//ul[@id="shop-by-category-list"]')
    for title in titles:
        links=title.xpath('.//a/@href')
        for lnk in links:
            print(lnk)
Selectivelinks(url)
```

Comment: can't you call **Selectivelinks(lnk)** where you have the print statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `links` returns a `list`. Then you can fetch the last 8 `links` using `links[:-8]`

Consider `x` contains a `list` of numbers from 1-10 then `x[-8:]` will return the last 8 items in the `list`

```
x = [i for i in range (0, 10)]
print x[-8:]
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Also known as [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks kiran.koduru, for your answer. This is what i was looking for.

Comment: Hey kiran.koduru, One more thing to ask: In some cases i noticed that if i use [0] operator it gives me the first link, on the other hand if i use for loop then it
gives all the links. However, i have also noticed that using [0] operator
also brings all the links of certain pages. Why is this variation?

Comment: You mean to say when you print `links[0]` it gives you the first link?

Comment: But, in some cases using links[0] i get all the links.

Comment: `links` is a `list` or consider it an `array` in other languages. When you print `links[0]`, you are looking for the `0` index in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity.